# Delphi TMenubar and TMenu on Windows & OSX - Tokyo 10.2.2

Tags: windows, macos, delphi, firemonkey

As per DocWiki:

[Using Menus in a FireMonkey Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Menus_in_a_FireMonkey_Application)

> Creating Menus for OS X and Windows
>
> Use the correct control for your target system (OS X vs. Windows).
>
> - For Windows applications, use the TMenuBar control:
>
>   - The main menu is placed in the client area of the form (standard for Windows).
>   - The menu items are not on the OS X menu bar (nonstandard for OS X).
> - For OS X applications, use the TMainMenu component:
>
>   - The main menu is placed in the non-client area of the Windows form (nonstandard for Windows).
>   - Menu items are placed on the OS X menu bar (standard for OS X).

So I choose `TMenuBar` for Windows and `TMenu` for OSX. But on Windows, both controls are showing.

My question is, how can I create 2 seperate controls in one Form? If I set `Visible` to False for all TMenu's Items, a blank menu bar is showing in Windows. As I set `TMenuBar.Visible = false` on MacOSX.

Also, if I used any Style on Windows, on closing the Form, an access violation occurs only for `TMenu`.

Is there a better way to design both on same Form, and not show a blank menu bar in Windows?

Comment: See [Using the FireMonkey TMenuBar's OSMenu Property to Place Your Main Menu for Windows and Mac](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42180) on EDN

Comment: OSMenu Property is not available any more. I saw the video of David I which was built by XE2.

Comment: I can not test with OSx, so just speculating. What if you skip `TMenuBar` and use `TMainMenu` on both? Does it look OK?

Comment: I tested using only TMainMenu, in Windows it raise exception if you use any Style, otherwise it's working fine. On my application I used Stylecontrol which makes problem on windows but not in OSX.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry to hear.

Comment: I use TMainMenu on both Windows and macOS and it looks pretty native to me on both OS'es.

Comment: @Hans did you use TStyleControl and TImageList? Is images are shown in MenuItem?

Comment: @shariful No, I did not add any images, only text. Using images in menus is Windows XP style ;-)

Comment: This is where the problem, try adding image on menu item and then see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use TMainMenu. The menu will appear in the client area of the form when your app is compiled for Windows and in the OSX menu bar when your app is compiled for OSX.